# Error in webservice-Rest Service?

Tags: rest-api, webservices, rest-service

I am following this blog Post [Shivasoft](http://www.shivasoft.in/blog/salesforce/getting-record-from-one-salesforce-organization-to-other/) where you can get Records From One Org to Another Using REST API. I have Followed the Same Thing As mentioned tin Blog Still I am Not getting any results

This is Vf Page

```
<apex:page controller="FetchAccount" standardStylesheets="true">
<style type="text/css">
.errorMsg{
    font-size:0.8 em;
    color:red;
}
</style>
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:form >
<apex:outputLabel value="UserName : " for="userName"/>
<apex:inputText required="true" id="userName" value="{!userName}" />
<br />
<apex:outputLabel value="Password : " for="pwd"/>
<apex:inputsecret id="pwd" value="{!pwd}"/>
<br />
<apex:commandButton id="getRecords" value="Get Records" action="{!fetch}" rerender="wrapper" status="waitStatus" />
<apex:actionStatus startText="Requesting..." stopText="" id="waitStatus"/>
<hr />
<apex:outputPanel id="wrapper">
<div class="errorMsg" style="display:{!displayError}"> {!errMsg} </div>
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!acc}" var="account" id="accTable" rowClasses="odd,even" styleClass="tableClass">

    <apex:column >
        <apex:facet name="header">Account Name</apex:facet>
         <apex:outputText value="{!account.name}"/>
    </apex:column>

    <apex:column >
        <apex:facet name="header">Created By</apex:facet>
         <apex:outputText value="{!account.CreatedBy.FirstName}"/>
    </apex:column>

    <apex:column >
        <apex:facet name="header">Phone</apex:facet>
         <apex:outputText value="{!account.Phone}"/>
    </apex:column>

</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:form>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

This is Controller

```
public with sharing class FetchAccount {

    //Login Domain May be test, prerellogin.pre
   // String LOGIN_DOMAIN = 'www.login';
    public String pwd{get;set;}
    public String userName{get;set;}
    public List<Account> acc{get;set;}
    public String errMsg{get;set;}
    public String displayError{get;set;}

    public FetchAccount()
    {
        displayError = 'none';
    }

    public void fetch()
    {
        errMsg  = 'Some error occurred, please try again';
        try
        {
        //-----------------------------------
        // Login via SOAP/XML web service api
        //-----------------------------------
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        **request.setEndpoint('https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/22.0');**
        request.setMethod('POST');
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8');
        request.setHeader('SOAPAction', '""');
        //not escaping username and password because we're setting those variables above
        //in other words, this line "trusts" the lines above
        //if username and password were sourced elsewhere, they'd need to be escaped below
        request.setBody('<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><Header/><Body><login xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com"><username>' + userName+ '</username><password>' + pwd+ '</password></login></Body></Envelope>');
        Dom.XmlNode resultElmt = (new Http()).send(request).getBodyDocument().getRootElement()
          .getChildElement('Body', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/')
          .getChildElement('loginResponse', 'urn:partner.soap.sforce.com')
          .getChildElement('result', 'urn:partner.soap.sforce.com');

        //-------------------------------
        // Grab session id and server url
        //--------------------------------
        final String SERVER_URL = resultElmt.getChildElement('serverUrl', 'urn:partner.soap.sforce.com') .getText().split('/services')[0];
        final String SESSION_ID = resultElmt.getChildElement('sessionId', 'urn:partner.soap.sforce.com') .getText();

        //----------------------------------
        // Load first 10 accounts via REST API
        //---------------------------------
        final PageReference theUrl = new PageReference(SERVER_URL + '/services/data/v22.0/query/');
        theUrl.getParameters().put('q','Select a.Phone, a.Name, a.CreatedBy.FirstName, a.CreatedById From Account a limit 10');
        request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint(theUrl.getUrl());
        request.setMethod('GET');
        request.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + SESSION_ID);

        String body = (new Http()).send(request).getBody();

        JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(body);

        do{
            parser.nextToken();
        }while(parser.hasCurrentToken() && !'records'.equals(parser.getCurrentName()));

        parser.nextToken();

        acc = (List<Account>) parser.readValueAs(List<Account>.class);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            displayError = 'block';
        }

    }
}
```

Only changes I have done in 4th line of Controller Where I have Comment And Hard coded the "login" in 25th line i.e-"request.setEndpoint"

But I am getting the Same Error Message  `errMsg  = 'Some error occurred, please try again';`

I have created the Remote site Settings also..Am I doing something wrong here OR Not ?

Comment: Can you put a System.debug(e) in catch block and see in debug logs what exactly the error you are getting.

Comment: @tandonprateek DEBUG|##############System.CalloutException: Unauthorized endpoint, please check Setup->Security->Remote site settings. endpoint = https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/22.0

Comment: ok ... as you already mentioned that you have added remote settings for end point but still you are getting this error.

Comment: ya...If i Add whole URL(above Comment) in Remote Site..This will be the Error DEBUG|##############System.CalloutException: Unauthorized endpoint, please check Setup->Security->Remote site settings. endpoint = https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/data/v22.0/query/?q=Select+a.Phone%2C+a.Name%2C+a.CreatedBy.FirstName%2C+a.CreatedById+From+Account+a+limit+10

Comment: you might also take a look at - http://cropredysfdc.com/2013/12/06/salesforce-to-salesforce-using-rest-part-i/